# Set arrays from response using Google visualization tools & Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to set two seperate arrays(headers & rows) to be equal to the response of the query I am making.

```js
let dataProp = {}
// I make the query
var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEz5wfWSwXbAgWhgvJxfxSDhNGf5w8hqVpAFbbAViEo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&sheet=Sheet2')

// I send the query to a function to be handled
query2.send(handleQueryResponse2)
function handleQueryResponse2(response) {

    // I want to inspect the response (shown below in image)
    console.log(response.getDataTable())

    data2 = response.getDataTable()
    dataProp.table2 = { rows: [...data2.fg] }

    // let's put this loop aside (this sanitizes the content in same data type.)
    for (let i = 0; i < data2.fg.length; i++) {
      let tempRow = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < data2.fg[i].c.length; j++) {
        tempRow[j] = cleanRowsContent(dataProp.table2.rows[i].c[j])
      }
      dataProp.table2.rows[i] = tempRow
    }
  }
```

Response of the query in console:

[image]

**Problem : Like shown in code, I want to grab the headers and rows like shown below BUT the values "If" & "fg" changes with updates (to "Fg" & "hg" and so on...) and I constantly have to check if my code is still working... Can someone explain me how I can fix this?**

*A little more context : I am using Google visualisation tools (to make multiple queries) because it is 97% lighter than the traditional jquery api format available*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, if you want to set properties on variable --> `dataProp`
need to use an object (`{}`), instead of an array (`[]`)

```
let dataProp = {};
```

next, rather than trying to access the data directly from the data table,
try converting the data table to json,
then grab the pieces you want...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  let dataProp = {};
  var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEz5wfWSwXbAgWhgvJxfxSDhNGf5w8hqVpAFbbAViEo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&sheet=Sheet2');

  query2.send(handleQueryResponse2);
  function handleQueryResponse2(response) {

    // convert data table to json
    data2 = JSON.parse(response.getDataTable().toJSON());

    // get rows
    dataProp.table2 = data2.rows;

    // get columns
    dataProp.table3 = data2.cols;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataProp));

  }

});
```

Comment: (dataProp is an object yes I made a typo, sorry)
But YES this is exactly what I needed to see thanks a lot!